# get distinct data of foreign key with count in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, relationship

I am facing a problem for counting distinct value from mysql in laravel.

**Project Model:**

```
public function projectNotes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectNote::class, 'project_id');
}
```

**ProjectNote Model:**

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'project_id');
}
```

**Database 'project_notes' table:**

```
id  project_id  note
1      1        Project 1 Note 1
2      1        Project 1 Note 2
3      1        Project 1 Note 3
4      1        Project 1 Note 4
5      2        Project 2 Note 1
6      2        Project 2 Note 2
7      2        Project 2 Note 3
8      3        Project 3 Note 1
9      3        Project 3 Note 2
10     4        Project 4 Note 1
```

**I need to get data like below:**

```
id  project     count
1      1        4
2      2        3
3      3        2
4      4        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withcount` to count records.

```
$projects = Project::withcount('projectNotes')->with('projectNotes')->get();
```

With this, you'll get `project_notes_count`